# video on demand streamin with jwplayer wowza android issue

Tags: jwplayer, wowza

I try to make jwplayer work on android phone when I put rtsp protocol file source it work fine in android but display an error that file can not be played in iOS and PC

without rtsp file source work on pc and iOS fine 
with rtsp file source work only in android

```
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
            playlist: [{
                sources: [
                        {file:'rtmp://localhost:1935/vod/mp4:dexter.mp4'}//used it to PC ,
                        {file:'rtsp://localhost:1935/dexter/dexter.mp4'}// used it to android,
                        {file:'http://localhost:1935/vod/mp4:dexter.mp4/playlist.m3u8'}//and this for iOS                       
                        ],
                title: 'dexter',

        width: 854,
        height: 480,
    });
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: in android device the player doesn't work unless you put the rtsp protocol path but if I put it other devices like iOS and PC doesn't work

Comment: You need to put the RTSP outside of the player setup.

Comment: RTSP inside the player work as well on android but in iOS and PC the player don't work

Comment: when I put the RTSP source file it work only on android but if I deleted it work well in iOS and PC

Comment: I solved the problem by checking if the device android and put rtsp if android thats solve the problem for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have Solved the issue by checking if the device is android or not

```
 var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        playlist: [{
            sources: [
                    (isAndroid)?{file:'rtsp://localhost:1935/vod/dexter/dexter.mp4'}:{file:'rtmp://localhost:1935/vod/mp4:dexter/dexter.mp4'},
                    {file:'http://localhost:1935/vod/mp4:dexter.mp4/playlist.m3u8'}                     
                    ],
    title: 'dexter',
    width: 854,
    height: 480,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put RTSP inside of the setup(), block, since neither Flash or HTML5 supports it.

You should do the work around mentioned here - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28856/using-apple-hls-streaming

HLS Live on Android

For live streams, there's not yet a good solution for playback on Android or other non-iOS mobile platforms. One workaround is to offer a native app for Android, in which HLS streams can be supported. This is beyond the scope of JW Player though. Another option, if you use the Wowza Media Server, is to offer a fallback RTSP stream for devices that don't support HLS. For example:

```
<div id="myElement">
    <a href="rtsp://example.com/vod/mp4:myVideo.mp4">watch this stream over RTSP</a>
</div> 

jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "http://example.com:1935/vod/mp4:myVideo.mp4/playlist.m3u8",
    image: "/assets/myPoster.jpg",
    fallback: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What no one seems to mention is the awful latency that HLS brings to the table with is "chunk video", it can be 30 seconds, if you are doing real-time streaming, like video surveylance, the RTMP and RTSP are the better solutions. RTSP works well on iOS & Android through VLC with 1 to 2 seconds of latency.

Comment: I agree. Still sometimes there are restrictions placed upon applications installed on the mobile devices depending on the client. Therefore the reason to use HLS is to provide a complete solution independent from third party software.