# Making jwplayer work for both android and iOS at the same time

Tags: android, ios, jwplayer, wowza

I've not been able to get this solved using any of the suggested fallbacks from multiple format. The answers given at the following post don't seem to work for me.
[video on demand streamin with jwplayer wowza android issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568993/video-on-demand-streamin-with-jwplayer-wowza-android-issue)
I've been trying to get the jwplayer to work both for android and iOS at the same time. My code is as follows:

```
<div id='playerBAenmNZAerlC'></div>

// Code to setup the jwplayer

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jwplayer('playerBAenmNZAerlC').setup({
                playlist: [{
                sources: [{ 
                    file: 'rtsp://54.164.51.65:1935/vods3/_definst_/amazons3/tiger1000/test1.mp4'
                },{
                    file: "http://54.164.51.65:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/tiger1000/test1.mp4/playlist.m3u8"
                }]

                }],
                image: '//www.longtailvideo.com/content/images/jw-player/lWMJeVvV-876.jpg',
                fallback: false,
                title: 'Bryan\'s Daughter',
                width: '100%',
                aspectratio: '16:9'
            });
        </script>
```

The above code works perfect for android devices, but it gives "Error while playing" on IOS devices. I've studied these links as well but couldn't get it work. You kind help would greatly be appreciated.
http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430218-using-hls-streaming
http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/5496622-streaming-on-android

Comment: Sorry, the error is "Error loading media: File could not be played"

Comment: Just use the m3u8, not rtsp, and set androidhls:true,

Comment: Thank you for your response @Ethan. can you tell me where can i set android androidhls:true ?

Comment: In your code, for example - fallback: true, androidhls: true,

Answer (score 1):

As Ethan JWPlayer stated, you must add

`androidhls: 'true'`

In your configuration. This was the ONLY change I did, and it now works GREAT!

Comment: You're the man, Andy! Ethan JWPlayer, thank you too! This saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want "fallback" set to "true".

This code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("player").setup({
                 sources: [
                    { file: "RTSP-LINK" },
                    { file: "HLS-LINK" },
                    { file: "RTMP-LINK" },
                 ],
                 rtmp: { bufferlength: 1 }, 
                 fallback: true, androidhls: true, width: 960, height: 540 });
  </script>
```

Comment: RTSP is not supported in JW Player.

Comment: If you try the above script with only a single RTSP link, you'll find that Android devices can play it. See this support thread: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/5404718-html5-livestreaming-with-hls-and-rtsp

Comment: @vitorKP. Thank you for your response, however this doesn't seem to work for me. Gives the same issue on IOS.